# Visual Basic & SQL Picturebox Controls

Tags: arrays, vb.net, picturebox

Using picture boxes overlaid onto an image as seen below.
[Click for Form Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pjsvc.jpg)

When the form loads if the student attends the class then the picturebox becomes a green tick. If the student does not attend the class the picturebox becomes blank.

Using SQL I can query the database to return all the classes that a specific student attends.
These classes are stored in an array StudentClass(n)

There are 50 classes on the timetable stored in an array AttendsClass(n). All  with a default value of False.
If the student attends a class then the specific attendsclass in the array becomes True.

Once the form is loaded the user can click on a picturebox to select that class and the corresponding attendsclass in the array becomes true.
Finally the user saves the form, inserting the classes back into the database.

The problem I have is in the Sub Form4_Load at the end, I currently have to repeat the same block of code 50 times. That simply checks if the student attends the class then sets the picture box = to an image of a tick on the GUI (_new.jpg).

```
enter code here
If AttendsClass(1) = True Then
        PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources._new
    End If
    If AttendsClass(2) = True Then
        PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources._new
    End If
    If AttendsClass(3) = True Then
        PictureBox3.Image = My.Resources._new
    End If
    If AttendsClass(4) = True Then
        PictureBox4.Image = My.Resources._new
    End If
```

Is it possible to put this into a loop to shorten my code. The code does work but its slow and lengthy so any improvements would be helpful.
Many Thanks Alex Currie
A Level Computing Student
Full Code:

```
enter code here
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form4
Public con As New OleDbConnection
Public ds As New DataSet
Public da As OleDbDataAdapter
Public cb As OleDbCommandBuilder
Public constring As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source    =" & Application.StartupPath & "\wma.accdb"
Public AttendsClass(50) As Boolean
Public StdID As Integer = Form2.DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells("StudentID").Value
Private Sub Form4_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim Forename As String = Form2.DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells("Forename").Value
    Dim Surname As String = Form2.DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells("Surname").Value
    Student.Text = "Student: " & Forename & " " & Surname
    If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        con.ConnectionString = constring
        con.Open()
    End If
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM StudentClass WHERE StudentId = " & StdID, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "Class")
    Dim Maxrow As Integer = ds.Tables("Class").Rows.Count
    Dim StudentClass(Maxrow) As Integer
    For n = 1 To 50
        AttendsClass(n) = False
    Next

    For n = 1 To Maxrow
        StudentClass(n) = ds.Tables("Class").Rows(n - 1).Item(1)
        For a = 0 To 50
            If StudentClass(n) = a Then
                AttendsClass(a) = True
            End If
        Next
    Next

    If AttendsClass(1) = True Then
        PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources._new
    End If
    If AttendsClass(2) = True Then
        PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources._new
    End If
    If AttendsClass(3) = True Then
        PictureBox3.Image = My.Resources._new
    End If
    If AttendsClass(4) = True Then
        PictureBox4.Image = My.Resources._new
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    If PictureBox1.Image Is Nothing Then
        PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources._new
        AttendsClass(1) = True
    Else
        PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
        AttendsClass(1) = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.Click
    If PictureBox2.Image Is Nothing Then
        PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources._new
        AttendsClass(2) = True
    Else
        PictureBox2.Image = Nothing
        AttendsClass(2) = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox4.Click
    If PictureBox4.Image Is Nothing Then
        PictureBox4.Image = My.Resources._new
        AttendsClass(4) = True
    Else
        PictureBox4.Image = Nothing
        AttendsClass(4) = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox3.Click
    If PictureBox3.Image Is Nothing Then
        PictureBox3.Image = My.Resources._new
        AttendsClass(3) = True
    Else
        PictureBox3.Image = Nothing
        AttendsClass(3) = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        con.ConnectionString = constring
        con.Open()
    End If
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    cmd.Connection = con

    'Deletes Existing Records To Be rewritten'
    cmd.CommandText = "DELETE * FROM StudentClass WHERE StudentID=" & StdID
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    For n = 1 To 50
        If AttendsClass(n) = True Then
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO StudentClass (StudentID, ClassID) VALUES (" & StdID & "," & n & ")"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End If
    Next
    Me.Dispose()
    MsgBox("Updated Successfully", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "WMA")
    con.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working example:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
 Handles PictureBox1.Click, ...., PictureBox50.Click
    Dim pic As PictureBox = CType(Controls(CType(sender, PictureBox).Name), PictureBox)
    'now you have clicked picturebox
    'you can change image by pic.Image = ...
    'if you want picturebox index, use line below:
    Dim picidx As Integer = CInt(CType(sender, PictureBox).Name.Replace("PictureBox", ""))

End Sub
```

VB2010Ex.